# iVPN Connection Problems

Tags: snow-leopard, ipod-touch, vpn

I want a way to create a secure connection to the internet (something I can trust) on my iPod Touch and Laptop through a source I can trust. In my research, it was suggested I use iVPN on my iMac at home to set up the connection. So I bought that and tried it out. The VPN client connects, but I cannot navigate to the internet. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, do you use your Laptop as router and connecting the iPod Touch to it with a VPN ?

Comment: No. I want to use my iMac (sorry didn't clarify that) that sits at home and use that to provide a secure connection to the internet when at the coffee shop or other public places.

Answer (score 2):

Doing so would require being able to access your iMac from remote places, thus configuring either a DMZ host, or port forwarding on your router. Either way it will be a headache.

Also if you're on a residential connection note that the public IP address can and will change. I recommend a dynamic DNS server for that.

Assuming you can get that all setup it's as simple as [setting up VPN](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1424) on your iDevice.

Comment: This is all setup already. The problem is the routing from VPN connection to the internet. It isn't working.